# I need a bitcoin or usd payment for my site

Tags: buy-bitcoins, payment, websites, java

Just service with simple API. I want to allow clients to pay usd or bitcoin. Then after payment complete i need to add my custom value on my site client purse. Is there simple system for it?
Back end server on java

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the Coinbase API: https://developers.coinbase.com/

Coinbase is very well known and trusted.

Then for the USD option you could have another button that links to Paypal, Stripe, 2Checkout, etc..